# Relative pronoun use (who/whom)

Tags: relative-pronouns, who-whom

1.This is the boy who works hard.
2.This is the boy who/whom all praise.
Why in first sentence who is in nominative case and in other accusative case?

Comment: In the first sentence the boy is doing something - working hard, and in the second he is having something done to him - being praised.  It is also worth noting that 'whom' derives from the OE dative, not the accusative.

Comment: Are there rules to identify whether the pronoun is in nominative or in accusative case

Comment: Cases are a relic of Old English and don't really exist in Modern English, and if you insist on applying them they are only a vague equivalent. I really wouldn't get too hung up on them. In "he killed her", 'he' is (allegedly) nominative because 'he' is the actor, doing something; 'her' is the (allegedly) accusative because she is the victim, having something done to her. It would be more normal to call them subject and object pronouns, rather that nominative and accusative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence the relative clause is derived from He (nominative) works hard. In the second sentence you have All praise him (accusative).

The structure of the two relative clauses is different. In the first one you have no subject after "who", so "who" is the subject of the relative clause. In the second one you have the subject "all" after "who". So "who/whom" can't be a nominative. By the way, "whom" is the accusative form of "who". Nowadays mostly replaced by who, as this does not lead to ambiguity.

Comment: That is what I already said in my comment...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation just to clarify little bit more  what is the case in this "The pen that you gave me is a very good one".

Comment: 'Whom' derives from OE dative, not accusative. It comes from the dative 'hwam', which contrasts with the nominative 'hwa' and the accusative 'hwone'. As such it is a cognate of the the German dative 'wem', so it is not really accurate to label 'whom' as an accusative.

Comment: If you take the basic sentence of the relative clause " You gave me the pen", me is indirect object/dative and the pen is direct object/accusative.

Comment: @RoaringFish   You are right, whom was originally a dative. But today, if whom is used it is used as an accusative, and "to whom/who ...to" as a dative.

Comment: @rogermue ~ indeed, but the point is that as 'whom' derives from dative and is a cognate of a current dative, *but is labelled as accusative in English*, then clearly applying labels such as nominative, accusative, and dative to Modern English is futile exercise in pigeon-holing. I know some grammarians say 'subject=nominative; object=accusative; indirect object=dative' but it doesn't really work as 'whom' shows. Why bother trying to force relics of another language onto English? Just call them subject, object, and indirect object.

Comment: @RoaringFish  I know the endless discussion about English not being Latin. -  I use the standard Latin grammar terms for all languages I know and don't see the sense that I should switch to a second set of grammar terms when I talk about English. I use the English terms often enough as I know there are people who are allergic to Latin case names. All the same, I find a second set of terms impractical. The chaos of grammar terms is big enough as it is.

Comment: @rogermue ~ the mistake you are making is thinking that it is 'a second set of terms'. It isn't. Modern English does not have nominative, accusative, dative, or any other case, as case revolves around inflecting the noun to reflect its function in a sentence, . Modern English doesn't do that because it is an analytic language, and the only remnant of case is the plural 's' and some pronouns. The chaos of terms you refer to is the result of trying to crow-bar concepts into a language that doesn't have them. Keep it simple. Call subjects and objects exactly what they are.

Comment: @RoaringFish So after all that, should I say *John met whom?* or *John met who?*

Comment: Say *John met who?*. It is 2016. Only weird people say *whom*.

Comment: I think regarding English as having nominative and accusative cases is actually very normal among linguists, and both Old English and Latin are largely irrelevant to the discussion.  You can say subjective and objective if you prefer, but it's not more common and the choice really *doesn't matter*.

Comment: Sorry guys after all this explanation still I am not able to grasp the topic firmly 1.This is the house that Jack built 2.Hari saw the man who had been hurt 3.Here the books which I found 4.the cat killed the rat that are the corn.5.bring me the book that you lent me ,point the case in this and please tell how you find case and why you think it is correct answer and what we can do to change it in other form,as if pronoun is in nominative/subjective case then change it to objective/accusative case

Comment: @AnshulNegi ①④⑤ *That* is no longer considered a relative pronoun in modern linguistics, but regardless of what you consider it, it doesn't have an accusative–nominative contrast, so the question isn't meaningful.  ③ *Which* is a relative pronoun, but it doesn't have an accusative–nominative contrast, so this question isn't meaningful, either.   ② *Whom* isn't possible in subject position.

Comment: @AnshulNegi The choice between *who* and *whom* has its own rules, different from other pronouns such as *he* and *him*.  You presented all these examples as though they were examples of the same phenomenon, but they're not; you'll have to learn when to use *who* and *whom* separately.

Comment: @RoaringFish *"That is what I already said in my comment"*.  Yes, well, but the site wants answers to be answers, not comments. The meta site meta.ell.stackexchange.com encourages users to write answers to questions that already have well-formulated comments. Plus, you could have written your own answer instead of engaging in such lengthy back-and-forth comments here.